# How to display sitemap on the 404 page in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8, sitemap

I am trying display sitemap in my 404 page. Could you recommended ways how can I display sitemap in my 404 page?

At now I tried use a sitemap module. I created 404 node page and installed Drupal 8 sitemap module. Then I created sitemap block in content region.  If I browse /404 page then only my node text is displayed, but not block where supposed to be sitemap.

Can I use some code?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to /admin/config/system/site-information, on the bottom you can set your default 404 page. So you can create a page with your sitemap on in, or just put in the path of your current sitmemap.

Comment: Thank you. I created already 404 page and and this in my node/5454 page.  If I am displaying my 404 page (node/5454) in browser then sitemap is shown. But if I put it /admin/config/system/site-information and write something fake url like /asd. Then it dosen't work. Only text is shown and not sitemap block in it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to to configure page which is available in this location  `/admin/config/system/site-information` there you have to give the link for 404 add `/sitemap` link. For reference i have attached Screen shoot. 
[image]